# A simple and non-confusing question on probability.

Tags: probability

Two men are playing cards.
Let's name them A and B  right?
Then A draws 2 cards out of the deck *"at a time".*
*And replaces followed by suffling back of deck*. The same work B does ...
*Find out the P(Their draws contain exactly one common card)*..

*Note:
*Kindly don't ask about my efforts here as it is not that big deal*.

I am confused how to interpret that common card..

Comment: Hint:  Say $A$ chooses $C_1,C_2$ (doesn't matter what they are).  What is the probability that $B$ chooses $C_1,X$ where $X\neq C_2$?

Comment: What I am confused at is :Will it allow the pair (C1,C2) and (C2,C1) both or only one of them.. meaning is both the pairs coming into existence or one pair should be taken..

Comment: I don't understand.  Will what allow that?

Answer (score 1):

The question concerns the following event: if A picks two cards $x \ne y$, then B should pick either $x$ but not $y$, or $y$ but not $x$. The probability that B picks one of the two cards is $2/52$ (assuming a standard deck) and the probability that B does not pick the other one is $50/51$. The answer is the product of these two numbers.

Comment: Let's say A takes (X,Y) where X not equals to Y.Will B be allowed to take both (Y,X) and (X,Y) or only one of them.

Comment: "Common card" refers to the intersection between the sets of cards picked by each player. The order in which you pick a card is irrelevant.

Comment: Why should I multiply them??